# If I start a new stack-exchange site, do I own it?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

If I propose and start and new overflow/exchange site, would I become the owner of it?  Or is there any ability for me to own it if I play a big role in making it successful?

Answer (score 10):

Basically, no. Content contributed to SE sites is owned by the poster (I think? don't quote me on that); the underlying technology as well as the look of the site etc. are owned by Stack Exchange Inc.

In the days of Stack Exchange 1.0, they tried a model in which you would own (or at least maintain primary control over) the sites you created, but it generally didn't work out well because without the support of the SE team, most of the sites fizzled out.

Answer (score 7):

You do *not* own it. Stack Exchange owns it.

You would be in a great position to be a moderator for that site, but that's about it.